# FindResource call returns NULL for text file with type RCDATA

Tags: c++, windows, embedded-resource

I'm writing a C++ program that needs to handle large chunks of data, specifically text files, however the data is longer than the given string limit. As a result I am attempting to load a text file as a resource file, however whenever I call FindResource the response is a null handle.

I have gone over other stack overflow posts, and MSDN to attempt to correctly implement this functionality however nothing I have tried has returned a valid handle.

C++ code:

```
HGLOBAL     res_handle = NULL;
HRSRC       res;
char *      res_data;
DWORD       res_size;

auto g_hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
res = FindResource(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_RESOURCE), RT_RCDATA);
std::cout << res << std::endl;
std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
res_handle = LoadResource(NULL, res);
std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
res_data = (char*)LockResource(res_handle);
std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
res_size = SizeofResource(NULL, res);
std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000
1813
87
87
87
```

Resource.h:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define MY_RESOURCE 300
// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        103
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40002
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Resource.rc:

```
MY_RESOURCE RCDATA "C:\\Users\\foobar\\Desktop\\projects\\foobar\\test0.txt"
```

Comment: Change the int to a name and use it without MAKEINTRESOURCE.

Comment: You can examine resources in your EXE. In Visual Studio, do `File > Open > File`, select your EXE, then click a little arrow next to Open button and choose `Open With > Resource Editor`. Check that the resource you are looking for actually exists. Most likely, the problem is with the build.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Igor, in Visual Studio I can see the actual resource in Resource Files -> Resource.rc -> RCDATA. Unless I am mistaken what you mean.

Comment: I changed the line of code you suggested Michael to "res = FindResource(g_hInstance, (LPCTSTR)MY_RESOURCE, RT_RCDATA);" and got the same output.

Comment: Like I said, check whether the resource is actually present in the EXE file that your project builds.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean Igor, I did what you suggested and I can see the file with my data with the id 300 as i defined.

Comment: @sal2kilo `(LPCTSTR)MY_RESOURCE` and `MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_RESOURCE)` are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.  I suspect something about your build setup is going wrong.

I started with an empty project in Visual Studio 2017 and the only thing I changed in the project settings was Configuration Properties > General > Character Set > "Use Unicode Character Set"

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

int main() {
  auto hinst = ::GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
  std::cout << hinst << std::endl;
  auto hrsrc = ::FindResourceW(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDTHING), RT_RCDATA);
  std::cout << hrsrc << std::endl;
  auto hglob = ::LoadResource(hinst, hrsrc);
  std::cout << hglob << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

resource.h

```
#define IDTHING 300
```

Resource.rc

```
#include "resource.h"

IDTHING RCDATA "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"
```

I completely avoided all the auto-generated resource stuff from VS and just wrote them as plain text files.

If you run in the debugger, stop after `hglob` is assigned and drop its value into a memory window, I can clearly see the PE header of notepad.exe.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and by simply replacing my string for the last parameter FROM L"RCDATA" to RT_RCDATA worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you receive error codes from GetLastError(), you should either call [FormatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) API (with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` flag) or use error lookup tool, “Tools / Error Lookup” in visual studio.

Code 1813 translates into the following message: “The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.”

As you see, it complains about resource **type**.

I don’t think you need RCDATA. It’s something very old from 16 bit windows. In Win32, custom resources types are strings, not integers. RCDATA is not even supported in the IDE.

The correct way — right click on your .rc file, “Add Resource”, “Import”, browse for the file you want to include, visual studio will ask you resource type, write any string e.g. `text` will do, then pass that string as the last parameter of FindResource function. If you're building with the default project settings, it's Unicode, so you'll need to pass Unicode string `L"text"` there.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `RCDATA`.  It is not "old", it is an officially supported and natively defined resource type, and plenty of modern apps still make use of it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It’s not exposed in the resource editor GUI of the visual studio. Very likely it still works when manually hacking the source files in the correct way, but visual studio wants to use string names for custom resource types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Technically yes, but practically, since MS released fully-featured community edition of VS in 2015, I don’t think these other IDEs are still relevant. At least not for C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fine, but OP obviously does: `Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.`